# Shared lock between App Service and Webjob

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I want to have a shared lock between the Webjob and the App Service code. I have tried lock keyword as well as mutex in C# but they don't seem to be working. Another alternative I could think of is Blob lease which is also the locking mechanism used for locking within webjobs environments as written [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Singleton).

Do azure webjobs run in a totally separate environments from the App Service such that the shared locks are not working, or am I missing something ? Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebJobs run in a separate process so a `lock` in C# will not work.

Lease on a blob is one way to make a distributed lock. Here is one article which can point you in the right direction with that: https://medium.com/veyotech/using-an-azure-lease-blob-as-a-distributed-mutex-a9608c918801

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Mutex is inter-process. Shouldn't that work in this scenario ?

Comment: Hmm, that is actually true. Those should work, however, they won't work across app service instances. Blob lease locking works there as well.

Comment: Do webjobs run on separate VMs from the App Service ? As I have read, mutex runs on the OS level, so only valid on a system

Comment: No, WebJobs will run on the same VM as long as they are in the same App Service Plan. The situation I mentioned is where you have multiple instances (VMs) in your App Service Plan, so a mutex cannot cross that boundary.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot @juunas.